# Petit lexique du sociolecte de Stack Exchange à l'usage des francophones

Tags: discussion, language

Étant donné que le français est largement — à raison — utilisé sur *French Language*, il serait bon d'établir un lexique du jargon de StackExchange pour ceux que le franglais rebute.

Ce lexique est à établir en wiki communautaire (tiens, tiens) en réponse de cette question.

Précisons encore une fois que l'objectif n'est pas d'établir un quelconque livre sacré, ni de contraindre le langage des utilisateurs de *French Language*. Ceci ne devrait être compris que comme un guide pour les indécis ne sachant pas comment francophoniser leurs messages.

<sub>Pardon pour le titre : je n'ai pas pu résister.</sub>

---

French is widely used on *French Language*, and it would be nice to establish some sort of a reference translation of the terms so we avoid the slippery slope of defaulting to [franglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais). This post is here for the community to work out translations of the jargon specific to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Badge** : Badge
- **Chat** : Clavarder, Clavardoir (pour les plus fanatiques de nos
  FLUtilisateurs)
- **Community Wiki**, **CW** : Wiki communautaire
- **Downvote** : voir [cette question sur le site principal](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/946/82)
- **Dupe(licate)** : Doublon
- **Edit** : Modifier, Modification
- **Excerpt** : Extrait (du wiki d'étiquette)
- **Flag** : Marqueur
- **Main** : Le site principal
- **Meta** : Méta
- **Moderator** : Modérateur
- **Off topic** : Hors-sujet
- **OP** :  voir [cette question sur le site principal](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1727/82)
- **Review** : Relire, vérifier, contrôler, corriger, relecture, inspecter
- **Rollback** : *[démantèlement](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertalen.php?woord=rollback&src=EN&des=FR)*, révocation, révoquer, annuler
- **Tag** : Étiquette
- **Tag Wiki** : Wiki d'étiquette
- **Upvote** : voir [cette question sur le site principal](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/946/82)

Comment: J'espère que _clavardoir_ est un substantif (comme un _boudoir_), parce que comme verbe, franchement, _clavarder_ a beaucoup plus de sens. De toutes façons, celui qui croit que je vais employer l'un ou l'autre habite à Coucouville-les-Nuées.

Comment: @Joubarc: C'était bien pensé ainsi :)

Comment: Depuis le temps que je me le demande : comment franciser **on hold** ?

Comment: @Fractaliste Je serais tentée de dire *en suspend*.